# Assigning a SQL result to variable from prepared statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure in MySQL and need to assign the results of a SQL query to a variable. The problem is that in order to create the SELECT statement, I have to use the CONCAT() function because I am passing in parameters.

Well it appears you can't use variables within the CONCAT function. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? The procedure I am trying to write is below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_proc` (IN tbl VARCHAR(20), IN col VARCHAR(20), IN id INT)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @myval VARCHAR(100);

    SET @t1 =CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl,' INTO @myval WHERE id = ',id );
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END //
```

Executing this gives me a SQL syntax error.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: You're setting ``@t1`` but you declared ``@myval``. Is that correct?

Comment: Here is the error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@myval VARCHAR(100); SET @t1 =CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl,' INTO @myv' at line 3)`

Comment: @acfrancis yes that is correct. I am wanting to set the result into `@myval`. `@t1` is just a string of the select statement.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to declare ``@t1`` don't you?

Comment: (im not MySql guru) questions: 1) is `@myval` accessible from the scope of EXECUTE? 2) try `CONCAT('SELECT RealColumn FROM RealTable INTO @myval WHERE id = RealId')` to localize the problem

Comment: @acfrancis no this is valid. I just tested with a declaration and still the same problem.

Comment: @jim interesting... I ended up just making this a simple string with hard coded values like this: `SET @t1 = 'SELECT...';` and still had a syntax error. So I removed the `DECLARE @myval VARCHAR(100);` and it was valid. However the procedure still doesn't work. 

After running the procedure the error this time was: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 5' at line 1`

Comment: @StaceyFriesen Look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html You dont need DECLARE statement at all

Comment: @StaceyFriesen also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139717/mysql-passing-procedure-params-to-execute-using-statement and this: http://www.examplesof.com/mysql/execute.html so you need EXECUTE... USING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```sql
...
-- SET @t1 = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl,' INTO @myval WHERE id = ',id );
SET @t1 = CONCAT('SELECT ', col, ' INTO @myval FROM ', tbl, ' WHERE id = ', id);
...
```

Check the documentation: [13.2.9.1. SELECT ... INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a477/1) with an example.

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (@t1 and @myval) and [13.6.4.1. Local Variable Syntax DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) (as could be: myval and t1), are different variables, therefore, it is not necessary to declare:

```sql
-- DECLARE @myval VARCHAR (100);
```

Comment: That's the one! The order was mixed up. Thanks!